# Ant salesforce.jar extensions

Tags: deployment, ant, licenses

I was trying to find some informations about running scripts after ant deployment and I found this thread:
[Run some script on deployment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30707/run-some-script-on-deployment)
That might be a silly question, but is the solution described there actually legitimate? I mean, isn't it violating any licenses?

Comment: I don't see what the problem would be here. However, you could consider shifting to use of [sfdx](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm) (which also supports anonymous Apex execution). We don't use the old Ant salesforce.jar stuff at all and instead execute sfdx from our build scripts (which are, coincidentally, written using Ant).

Comment: @PhilW can't do sfdx on the project. Anyway, my concerns were that you basically extend their functionalities. You use their authentication to do your own stuff. Also, their jar is not really open source ;d

Comment: Since they are simply implementing standard Ant APIs I can't see they can prevent you from augmenting their functionality. Obviously they could change the names of their tasks and the additional methods exposed and this will break your code, but that's something to worry about if and when. And I'd suggest it is rather unlikely since sfdx has basically replaced this Ant scripting.

Comment: BTW, you can use sfdx CLI with metadata API structured projects too.

Comment: @PhilW sure, but in order to use it server-side you need to create a connected app, and I didn't get approval to create one for that purpose yet.

Comment: @PhilW little snippet in CI implementation

Comment: @PhilW according to salesforce documentation, in order to use Salesforce CLI in CI environments you need to create and configure connected app https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm#sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow

Comment: @PhilW I understand and agree that sfdx is the way to go. I'd be interested what is your authorization flow if you didn't create connected app for that purpose yourselves. Actually, maybe I'll just try that image you mentioned and see if I can work around that

Comment: Actually, I just checked and the dev who set up our CI did actually set up JWT for the CI environment to use, and did add a connected app. Sorry for the confusion. A detail he didn't previously share! ;) Sorry for that.

Comment: Ha, I see :D Atm I'm trying to push my leads in that direction, so I won't have to do any tricky stuff, the original question was just to figure something out in case of their refusal. Thanks for help!

Comment: There is an alternative approach that uses an "auth URL". Take a look at the [sfdx auth](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_auth.htm) commands. This [post](https://medium.com/@medben/sfdx-org-authorization-%EF%B8%8F-a75b54861b54) might also be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Licence file clearly states:

> ## Force.com Web Service Connector End User License Agreement
>
> Except as described below, Force.com Web Service Connector (WSC) is
> Copyright (c) 2005-2013, salesforce.com, inc. All rights reserved.
>
> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
> modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
> met:
>
> - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>   documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
> - Neither the name of salesforce.com, inc. nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
>   this software without specific prior written permission.
>
> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
> "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
> LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
> A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
> OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
> SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
> LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
> DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
> THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
> (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
> OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

So, you're allowed to use it with or without modification (including creating your own extensions, by definition) in your projects. Note that you have to actually download and open the JAR file in order to find this file, as it doesn't seem to appear on any pages for the tool (download, documentation, etc). But never fear, you're free to do with it as you wish as long as you follow the few basic rules they have for its use.